# Typecasting over a message queue in c

Tags: c, linux, casting, ipc

I am currently trying to send an integer over a message queue. I am typecasting the address of this integer to a (char *) since in the future I would like to accept other data types and this data is sent in a struct designed for use in message queues.

Over a message queue (which I have verified to be working correctly), I am sending a struct Type:

```
struct Type{

    long mtype;
    char *data;
};
```

To send the message, the following code is executed from the sending process:

```
struct Type* ack = malloc(sizeof(struct Type));
int temp = 999;

ack->mtype = 1;
ack->data = (char *)&temp;


if(msgsnd(msqid, ack, sizeof(struct Type) - sizeof(long), 0) == -1){

          perror("Sending acknowledgement to producer\n");

}
```

On the receiver end, the following is then executed:

```
struct Type *rack = malloc(sizeof(struct Type));

rack->mtype = 1;

//Wait for acknowledgement from server
if(msgrcv(prodmsqid, rack, sizeof(struct Type) - sizeof(long), 0, 0) == -1){ 

       perror("msgrcv for acknowledgement from server");

            exit(1);


 }
 printf("Acknowledgement has arrived: %d\n",(int)rack->data);
```

The output of this printf varies from very large numbers(8171536) to 4.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `*(int*)rack->data`? And why not change the `data` member of your struct to a `int` instead of a `char` pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are passing an address that is on the stack, the int address cast as a char address.  But that int location goes out of scope right after the send.  One fix, if I'm right about that, would be to make the int location global.

Comment: I did modify the int location to global, but to no avail. I also tried to allocate memory on the heap to store the int but the same results were produced. 
I modified the data field in the Type struct to an integer for testing purposes. The operation to send and receive were also obviously modified to send or receive an int instead of a char*.
The int was received successfully. Thus I guess my problem occurs in the typecasting to char*

Comment: I have modified the sizes of both msgrcv and msgsend to sizeof(Type) only. This has caused the output to be correct. However everywhere I have looked, it is suggested to remove the size of the long in the struct, like I was doing previously. Could bump into any repurcussions if I do not remove it?

Comment: You're right about the documentation and removing the size of the long.  I can't think of any reason that you'd get burned by sending more than you want and ignoring the extra.  It just doesn't seem very clean, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Type{

    char *data;
    long mtype;
};
```

That will give you what you want.

Comment: I did modify the order of the variables, but the result did not change. I'm passing long as the first type in the data structure to conform with the general data structure accepted by msgrcv; http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv

Comment: Right.  Sorry, I was reading too fast.  I think I do see the problem now, and will post a better answer.